Spring scheduled job how to make it resilient
How can you make a spring scheduled cron job resilient, i have a service that runs at 2pm and causes a db record to be created. It also causes another call to a service.
I need to cater for service failures, i can use retry on the external service
but how can i ensure that the cron fires? what if it fires but before the service creates a record it dies

maybe you can look into quartz scheduler. it has been a long time, but for persistent scheduled jobs it was the gold standard some time ago..
